# AWS SageMaker: Use S3 pickled models instead of hosting on sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I am working on a use-case for which I have to use Amazon SageMaker notebook instances. Amazon SM resources are filled with material that works well for single model i.e. you do your thing locally on NB Instance and then deploy the model as an endpoint. My use-case on the other hand has multiple models for multiple customers and this needs to be automated. i.e. once a customer uploads a file, a model needs to be automatically created and stored.

Current approach is to automate SageMaker instances through lambda for picking up the train data, training the data and saving the model back to S3 before closing the instance.

My question is, is this the right approach? Or should I create an endpoint for each model for each customer? Somehow since the data size is going to be small and I am working with SageMaker for the first time, I am more comfortable with saving the models in S3 than deploying many many endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the most efficient technical implementation will depend on things like the customer's business and security requirements as well as if the models are being trained on different groupings of the data (ex: model for each city).

Deploying multiple models on a single endpoint will certainly be cheaper and easier to manage over time.  If each model is trained on a different dataset for each customer then you could deploy an endpoint for each customer and manage different model variations per endpoint.  If all of these customers are using the same data and model output then the multi-model endpoint would make sense.  Whereas, if dataset/models are tied to specific independent customer then the one model per endpoint would make more sense.

This video explains it so well + has blog posts going into more detail:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dT8jmdF-ZWw